# How to hide a button component on a particular route in react-router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-v4

I am new to javascript and react. I have done lots of Googling with no solution. I am trying to hide a button component on one of three pages/routes where it currently displays but when I try to do it, it hides on all the pages/routes. Here is the code:

```
const routes = [
  { 
    path: '/:bookId/details',
    title: 'Book Details', 
    component: BookDetailsPage, 
    hideButton: true 
  },
  { 
    path: '/:bookId', 
    title: 'Details', 
    component: BookPage,
    exact: true, 
    hideButton: false 
  },
  { 
    path: '/',
    title: 'Book',
    component: BookListPage, 
    hideButton: false
  }
];

const Page = (): React.ReactElement => {

  const isBookDetailsPage = routes[0].hideButton; //returns true

  return (
      <ContentMasterLayout
        title="Book"
        action={
          <Box display="flex">
            //this approach hides the button on all pages
            {!isBookDetailsPage &&
               <BookButton transactionId={match?.params.bookId} />}
          </Box>
        }
      >
        <LocalRouter routes={routes} />
      </ContentMasterLayout>
  );
};
```

Please any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use the `hideButton` value as it'll always be true for every other page,

I'll check the current page by looking at the pathname on the route and if the route has details then `isBookDetailsPage` is `true` and if not then it's `false`

So technically your code should look like this

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';

const Page = (): React.ReactElement => {
  
  const location = useLocation();
  
  // will be true/false
  const isBookDetailsPage = location.pathname.includes('details');

  return (
      <ContentMasterLayout
        title="Book"
        action={
          <Box display="flex">
            {!isBookDetailsPage &&
               <BookButton transactionId={match?.params.bookId} />}
          </Box>
        }
      >
        <LocalRouter routes={routes} />
      </ContentMasterLayout>
  );
};
```

In the example above, I used the `useLocation()` hook on [react-router-dom V5.1,](https://reacttraining.com/blog/react-router-v5-1/#uselocation) but you can also use `props.location.pathname` or the plain javascript `window.location.pathname`